# infragistics timeline hide days

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, timeline

I'm using Infragisitics for Winforms 's, `UltraTimeline` component and I try to hide Sunday from my timeline.
Enabled and Visible attributes don't do anything :

```
Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSchedule.DayOfWeek dayOfWeek1 = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSchedule.DayOfWeek(System.DayOfWeek.Sunday);
dayOfWeek1.Enabled = false;
dayOfWeek1.Visible = false;
```

Anyone can help me ? Give me ideas ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design as the UltraTimeLineView was based on MS Project and the Journal view in MS Outlook and neither of them support hiding a day either.  Most likely this is because the concept of a "timeline" suggests a continuous, unbroken representation of time.

It is a new product idea for the UltraTimeLineView to support hiding of a day of the week and you can log this on the [Infragistics ideas site](http://ideas.infragistics.com/forums/192359-windows-forms).